# Alternatives to the stack and heap-based memory models

Tags: memory-management

The stack seems to be an optimization of memory use for a specific application. Whereas the heap is a general model that works in all cases. Wondering if there are any other types of models of computer memory allocation that are optimized for different use cases.

Following from this:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222564/are-there-alternatives-to-stackheapstatic-memory-model

> Way back in the day, that's exactly how it happened, programmers planned ahead of time exactly what each RAM location would be used for.

Wondering what might have been some of the techniques for allocating memory for specific use cases back in the day, or today.

Comment: Do you mean like region-based allocation (e.g. zone allocation), object pools,  slab allocation? Or older techniques such as overlays?

Comment: Both I guess :)